# Storing Data on URL change

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, url, url-routing

I am getting a URL from `PIC 32 controller` using it's post function.

which is like, `www.example.com/Default.aspx?x=12&y=23`

What I want to do is that when I get the URL, I want to store the values of x and y into `SQL Server`.

As `PIC Controller` cannot generate the button event so I need to store the data when the URL is being post on the server.

As per I think this needs to be done on page load. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes do it in a page load.

Access those strings using below syntax:

```
int x=Integer.ParseInt(Request.QueryString("x").ToString)
int y=Integer.ParseInt(Request.QueryString("y").ToString)
```

Then insert the values into database.